# How to display page in entire screen instead of target frame

Tags: html

I am working on a web project. I divided the page in the ratio 40:60 using `<frameset>` tag and the screen looks like this,

[image: this is the 40% content]

When I click on any of the links "salesplan","tracking","reports" the corresponding page will be displayed in the remaining 60% screen portion. like this,
[image: tracking page]

and follows....

Now if I click on a logout page, logout message will be displayed on the next frame....(60% of the screen). But i want to display this page in entire screen i.e, 100% screen instead displaying it in target frame.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I _hope_ you don't actually have the password in the querystring.

Comment: Frames are deprecated; you should consider using CSS instead for a much better experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `target="_top"`to your link:

```
<a href="logour.php" target="_top">Logout</a>
```

The `target` attribute can be used to direct links to another location, other than your current frame. If you want to load the link in another frame instead of the top page, use `target="framename"`, where `framename` is the value of the `name` attribute of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

set 'target' property.

example:

```
<a href="http://aaa.com/logpout.html" target="_parent">Logout</a>
```